# show django errors when using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-forms

I want to use ajax in my invitation form. It is a simple form which is about posting email. I did the invitation form with the ajax but i could not show django specific error. For example, if i try to post the same email address, it should throw an error saying

> this email already exist and also if i provide the email as abcd@gmail my ajax code says success. How could i validate for such condition when using ajax?

```
$('.invitation-form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // preventing from the brwoser default behavior for form submission
  console.log('event', event.target);
  requestInvitation();
})

function requestInvitation(){
  console.log('request');
  console.log($('.requested_email').val());
  $.ajax({
    url: '/invitations/request/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {email: $('.requested_email').val(), csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},

    success: function(data) {
      $('.requested_email').text('');
      $('.display').html("<div class='ui floating message'>Success</div>")
      console.log('data', data);
    },

    error: function(xhr,errmsg,err){
      $('.display').html("<div class='ui floating message'>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+"</div>"); // want to show django specific error
    }
  })
}

@csrf_exempt
def requestInvitation(request):
    form = InviteForm(request.POST or None)
    response_data = {}
    if form.is_valid():
        join = form.save(commit=False)
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        already_join, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        if created:
            already_join.invite_code = get_invite_code()
            already_join.save()
            response_data['result'] = "Thank you for your interest"
            response_data['email'] = email
            send_request_received_email.delay(email,already_join.email_tracker)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'invitation/invitation.html', context)
```

**html**

```
<form method="POST" class="invitation-form vcenter">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="ui action input">
                <input type="email" class="requested_email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <button class="ui button primary">Request Invite</button>
              </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Your not actually considering the erroneous case in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it has been created, it will include the message in the 
`response_data['result']`

```
@csrf_exempt
def requestInvitation(request):
    form = InviteForm(request.POST or None)
    response_data = {}
    if form.is_valid():
        join = form.save(commit=False)
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        invite, created = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
        if created:
            invite.invite_code = get_invite_code()
            invite.save()
            response_data['result'] = "Thank you for your interest"
            response_data['email'] = email
            send_request_received_email.delay(email,already_join.email_tracker)
        else: 
            response_data['result'] = "The email already exists"
            response_data['email'] = email
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")

    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'invitation/invitation.html', context)
```

I have not tested this, but let me know if it works.

Comment: data.result shows nothing both in success and error function. Also if i fill the existed email, i get success message.

Comment: if i console data, i get the whole html template.

Comment: Are you sure your form is valid?

Comment: Try adding `status=500` to the `return HttpResponse()` in the else statement.

Comment: it is not entering into the is_valid block.

Comment: invalid block is rendered first. Why is that so?

Comment: Make sure your form is valid. If you already have created a `InviteForm`, try to render it instead of writing the form manually.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting a json object response for both success and error? A simple example would be:

```
    from django.http import JsonResponse

    def ajax_form(request):
        form = SomeForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # other logic here. Format response how you like.
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Success message'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Error message'}, status=500}
```

Javascript:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some_url',
        data: 'some_data',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.message);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    },
```